# Custom API endpoint for ActiveReports 17 .NET core and Angular solution

Tags: asp.net, .net, angular, activereports, grapecity

I'm developing a dotnet 7 and Angular solution, backend and frontend are not on the same server. I have installed Active Reports 17 for .NET to generate some reports.

The issue is that I can't get to the API endpoint, because Active Reports is pointing to the frontend server instead of the backend.

Is there any way to specify a custom endpoint for Active Reports ? instead of the default server address that Active Reports is deployed on, I specify the backend url.

solution of Active Reports API endpoint